# Google API + Oauth2 + Ruby - I cannot call APIs

Tags: ruby, google-api

I am using the sample code from Google to access drive and calendar through the API.  I have no problem getting through the oauth2 sequence and getting the code.  I can then exchange the code for an access token, although it takes way too much time (75 seconds). This is problem #1.  Clearly I can't have a user sitting there for well over a minute to get the token.

When trying to actually pull data from an API endpoint, it times out after a minute.

I can use the APIs Explorer and everything works fine.  When I try to hit it up programmatically from Ruby I simply can't get anything to work.

I can't even get Google's code to work:

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby

I follow those steps, still get a timeout using their unmodified code.

I feel like I'm missing something really really fundamental here.

FWIW I have no problem running the PHP sample.

Comment: You need to create a service account if you want to access the drive api without user authentication each time

Comment: User auth is fine, and I save the tokens.  Please read what I wrote: works in php, not in ruby.  I also use the token from ruby in the php code and it works.  The ruby code is likely just broken, not sure.

Comment: Are you using the gem 'google-api-client' ?

Comment: I'm running this code: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/ruby-samples/blob/master/drive/quickstart/quickstart.rb
Yes, it uses google-api-client.

Comment: Refer to the documentation here https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client

Comment: I just realized this is related to an issue that I've had before.  On my Mac, Ruby cannot connect to a socket if the domain name resolves to multiple IP addresses.  Ugh.